# How to implement Braintree escrow

Tags: braintree

I want to implement escrow of Braintree in my website. But escrow is not holding. My code is

```
`require_once "lib/Braintree.php";
Braintree_Configuration::environment("sandbox");
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId("id");
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey("key");
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey("key");

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(
array(
'amount' => "100.00",
'merchantAccountId' => 'blue_ladders_store',
'creditCard' => array(
'number' => "378282246310005",
'cvv' => "1234",
'expirationDate' => "12/2017",
 ),
 'options' => array(
 'submitForSettlement' => true,
  'holdInEscrow' => true
   ),
  'serviceFeeAmount' =>'1'

   )
   );`
```

This code is working fine for normal transaction because transactions are showing in my dashboard. But when releasing amount from escrow it showing 
"message: Cannot release a transaction that is not escrowed."
It means my transaction is not Escrow. Is it a problem of location? I am hitting the service from India. Any problem with the location.
Please help me for escrow.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work as a developer for Braintree</sub>
​

You must be a Marketplace merchant and you and all sub-merchants must be domiciled in the US to hold money in escrow. You are most likely receiving this error because you do not meet the compatibility requirements listed [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/marketplace/overview#compatibility).
​
I recommend reaching out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com) to review your integration and discuss your options.
​